# How safe is it to update base?

Tags: haskell, cabal

On ubuntu I currently have haskell-platform 2011.2.0.1.2 installed, and I
am currently working on some code where it would be very nice to have
`Control.Concurrent.Chan` be an instance of `Eq`. Unfortunately, in
`base-4.3.1.0`, which is the one I have installed, it is not, but in
`base-4.4.0.0` `Chan` is an instance of `Eq`.

Would it be possible to update base, maybe by sandboxing it with `cabal-dev` or any
other method, in a way that would not break too many packages?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you should never upgrade `base`. It's one of the [boot packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Libraries) — the packages that GHC itself needs to build, and ships with — and upgrading them will lead to Very Bad Things™. (Here's a [full list of boot packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/packages); everything with a `-` in the `tag` column is one. Don't upgrade these!)

Indeed, cabal-install's `cabal upgrade` feature was removed precisely because it had a nasty tendency to upgrade boot packages.

Not only is it a boot package, but being such core functionality, it's pretty much inherently tied to a specific GHC version. Your best option is to install the corresponding newer version of GHC in a local directory.